# Use 2 column to generate absent and present matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a data.frame:

```
df[19:30,]
   gene     sample
19 rtxA sample-320
20 rtxA sample-359
21 rtxA sample-594
22 vibF sample-350
23 vibF sample-346
24 vibF sample-349
25 vibF sample-368
26 vibF sample-362
27 vibF sample-363
28 vibF sample-369
29 vibF sample-345
30 vibF sample-326
```

the df only show 2 elements in gene (rtxA and vibF) column, nevertheless it present 150 genes, and in sample column are 21 samples (sample-320 ... sample-x), so I want just convert it to absent/present data.frame (or matrix) using the samples as columns and gene as rows. Something like:

```
    sample-320  sample-359  sample-594 sample-350 .....
rtxA     1          1             0          0
vibF     0          0             1          1
```

If present 1, and 0 if absent.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `table`

```
+(table(df) > 0)
```

---

Or do

```
table(unique(df))
```

-output

```
   sample
gene   sample-320 sample-326 sample-345 sample-346 sample-349 sample-350 sample-359 sample-362 sample-363 sample-368 sample-369
  rtxA          1          0          0          0          0          0          1          0          0          0          0
  vibF          0          1          1          1          1          1          0          1          1          1          1
      sample
gene   sample-594
  rtxA          1
  vibF          0
```

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(val = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "sample", values_from = val, values_fill = 0)
```

```
#> # A tibble: 2 x 13
#>   gene  `sample-320` `sample-359` `sample-594` `sample-350` `sample-346`
#>   <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 rtxA             1            1            1            0            0
#> 2 vibF             0            0            0            1            1
#> # ... with 7 more variables: sample-349 <dbl>, sample-368 <dbl>,
#> #   sample-362 <dbl>, sample-363 <dbl>, sample-369 <dbl>, sample-345 <dbl>,
#> #   sample-326 <dbl>
```

##### Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "   gene     sample
rtxA sample-320
rtxA sample-359
rtxA sample-594
vibF sample-350
vibF sample-346
vibF sample-349
vibF sample-368
vibF sample-362
vibF sample-363
vibF sample-369
vibF sample-345
vibF sample-326", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```